# 1-n arguments in constructor with interface

Tags: typescript

I have an interface:

```
interface I {
    new(name: string, ...args: any[]);
}
```

And classes with constructors like this:

```
constructor(name: string) { }
constructor(name: string, a: number) { }
constructor(name: string, a: string, b: string, c: string, d: string) { }
constructor(name: string, x: { b: boolean }) { }
```

It always tells me the implementation does not fit the interface.

I thought it would be sufficient to use `, ...args: any[]` but it's not.

This is a syntax error: `, ...args?: any[]`.

Even when I have all rest arguments optional, like [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504670/typescript-variable-number-of-parameters-in-function-interface-definition-0-9-5) it yield the same error:

```
constructor(name: string, a?, b?, c?) { }
```

[In one of those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702548/constructor-overload-in-typescript), someone advices to just not use a constructor prototype in the interface (yes, I also tried overloading without success). But it would be nice to have a constructor interface with at least this `name: string` and the rest to be optional.

**How can I have constructors with 1 mandatory and 0-n optional arguments?**

Comment: I don't think you can define a constructor signature in your interface. At least not like that. Check this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13408029/2300664

Comment: Also this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes

Answer (score 1):

@Seamus gave you correct answer. You cant implement static properties of the class defined in interface. But you can still check against them. Read the links he provided - they explain the issue quite well.

I can't post a link to more detailed example in the comments so I post it here: [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20I%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new(name%3A%20string%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FYou%20cant%20implement%20new%20in%20classes%20below%0D%0Aclass%20AI1%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20AI2%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string%2C%20a%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20AI3%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string%2C%20a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20string%2C%20c%3A%20string%2C%20d%3A%20string)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20AI4%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string%2C%20x%3A%20%7B%20b%3A%20boolean%20%7D)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Other%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(name%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FBut%20you%20can%20still%20use%20this%20interface%20like%20this%0D%0Afunction%20createObj(ctor%3A%20I%2C%20name%3A%20string%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20new%20ctor(name%2C%20...args)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FNo%20problems%20here%0D%0Alet%20ao1%20%3D%20createObj(AI1%2C%20%221%22)%3B%0D%0Alet%20ao2%20%3D%20createObj(AI2%2C%20%221%22%2C%201)%3B%0D%0Alet%20ao3%20%3D%20createObj(AI3%2C%20%221%22%2C%20%222%22)%3B%0D%0Alet%20ao4%20%3D%20createObj(AI4%2C%20%221%22%2C%20%7B%20b%3A%20true%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FBut%20here%20you%20will%20get%20an%20error%0D%0Alet%20err%20%3D%20createObj(Other%2C%20%221%22)%3B)

Comment: I don't want a proxy-like method to create instances :-/

Comment: How do you want to create them?

Comment: `new MyClass("Name");`

Comment: Why do you need interface to do this?